# How to get list of tables without any active triggers?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, triggers

I have database in SQL Server 2008 with triggers on almost every table. I need to review tables without active triggers.
How to get list of all tables without any active triggers (tables without any triggers or those tables where all triggers are disabled)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can anti semi join between `sys.tables` and `sys.triggers`.

e.g. with `NOT IN`

```
SELECT *
FROM   sys.tables
WHERE  object_id NOT IN (SELECT parent_id
                         FROM   sys.triggers
                         WHERE  is_disabled = 0)
```

Or `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT *
FROM   sys.tables t
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   sys.triggers tr
                   WHERE  is_disabled = 0
                          AND tr.parent_id = t.object_id)
```

Neither `sys.tables.object_id` or  `sys.triggers.parent_id` are nullable and in this case both give [the same semantics and plan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11074428/73226).

Comment: @ErikE - That's my default position too but here both `object_id` and `parent_id` are `NOT NULL`-able so will give the same plan as `NOT EXISTS`

Comment: I just don't like `IN` syntax... *ever*, except for a list of scalars or column names. :)

Comment: Added the `NOT EXISTS` version.

Comment: Of course you are 100% right that the `IN` is just fine here. I have seen some nasty triply- or quadruply-nested `IN` queries, though--where joins or `EXISTS` to a single `INNER JOIN`ed set of tables would have been far superior. So I lean away from `IN` because it seems to help foster this kind of messy query thinking in the inexperienced (which you are *not*).